# WCF: No service response from the server side

Tags: c#, wcf

I just noticed the remote server accepts calls from any client but only responds to a few of them. I can telnet the same host & ip from any client.

I set a breakpoint at the server side but it never trapped if I connected from unlucky client.

Another clue; I could get response if I only used ip adress instead of hostname:

> C:\NET>Hello.exe remoteserver 1333
>
> No response
>
> C:\NET>Hello.exe 192.168.35.211 1333
>
> Response from service: Server v3.32

You might thing it's a binding related but here is another symptom:

**Client A**

> C:\NET>Hello.exe 192.168.35.211 1333
>
> Response from service: Server v3.32

**Client B**

> C:\NET>Hello.exe 192.168.35.211 1333
>
> No response

As you see it looks very weird and I'm totally lost.

This is the client project's Pastebin code: [Hello.cs](http://pastebin.com/Zmn2czDh)

And this is the server's related section: [Server.cs](http://pastebin.com/qUyScRZj)

Why does the server "choose" the clients?  What would be the reason?

Comment: Chances are it's how the endpoint is configured. Either the server is set to only accept IPs, or you're hard-coding an IP endpoint and explicit matching on the request.  EDIT: Take a look at [`<useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee816894.aspx) and how you're binding your service `<baseAddresses>`.

Comment: @Nime Cloud Glad you could solve it. Please add your update as an answer, so other people can see it is solved.

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE**

OK, I trapped the error at client side, during a service call:

> The server has rejected the client credentials.

And the solution:

```
    NetTcpBinding tcpBind = new NetTcpBinding();
    tcpBind.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None;
```